# Upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04 to kernel 6.2.0.26 fails to boot

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 system from Linux kernel 5.19.0.50 to 6.2.0.26 and the machine won't even get past the initial load. It seems that there is some issue with a couple of the Kernel Modules (efi_pstore and drm) not getting loaded. I don't get the "Finished Load" messages in the log.

Booting with the 5.19.0.50 works.

I am not using any Nvidia drivers which seems to have caused issues for other people.

The machine is running on a Gigabyte Z370 AORUS Gaming 5 with an 8600K CPU and an Nvidia RTX 3070.

Any suggestions on how to proceed from here?

The successful boot on 5.19.0.50 has:

```
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k kernel: EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p6): re-mounted. Quota mode: none.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Activating swap /swapfile...  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k kernel: Adding 2047996k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:7 across:18735104k SSFS  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Activated swap /swapfile.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Reached target Swaps.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: **Finished Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.**  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Starting Platform Persistent Storage Archival...  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k kernel: ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: **Finished Load Kernel Module drm.**  
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k kernel: lp: driver loaded but no devices found
Aug 05 13:53:22 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Platform Persistent Storage Archival.
```

Which are missing in the 6.2.0.20 log:

```
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd-journald[331]: Journal started  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd-journald[331]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/08163643f37a443b903c3c02ec70732a) is 8.0M, max 320.2M, 312.2M free.  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Started Journal Service. 
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module chromeos_pstore.  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd[1]: Reached target Preparation for Local File Systems.  
Aug 05 13:52:38 ubuntu-8600k systemd-journald[331]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/08163643f37a443b903c3c02ec70732a is 24.153ms for 1016 entries.
```

Comment: I have been able to resolve the issue with booting under 6.2.0.26 by installing the NVIDIA 535 driver. It would seem there is some issue with the Nouveau driver and my RTX 3070 card.

Comment: I had the same issue when I upgraded to `6.2.0.26`, I had `nvidia-515`. I had to go into recovery and then purge the nvidia drivers to be able to boot up.

Comment: Update: I installed the newest drivers  using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-535` and I was able to boot back with working `nvidia-smi`. Also, I had to do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or else the system was stuck while booting off. Oooof :) . Note that I just upgraded to Linux 6.2.0.26 early this week and have been postponing reboot until today.

Answer (score 1):

I runt into the same problem on a Dell Precision 3470 with an Nvidia T550 graphic card, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS after an `apt upgrade` and reboot.
Based on what I tried (see below), it seems to be linked to interaction between Nouveau open source drivers for Nvidia cards and kernel 6.20.

### How to fix

I'm describing here how I solved it for reference to others.
Please note that this is just a workaround to get back to a working PC using kernel 5.19.

1. If your setup does not show GRUB menu on boot, hit `Shift` while booting to get to it
2. Select `Advanced options for Ubuntu`, then `Ubuntu with Linux 5.19.0-50-generic` (your options may differ slightly, just select the latest version that is not 6.2.x).
   Your system should now boot fine; if it doesn't, try with a different kernel.
3. Once you get to the desktop, open a terminal and then

   ```
   $ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep submenu
   submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-a8bbd8f4-68d3-4a3d-836d-a75021372c04'
   ```

   Note this first `$menuentry_id_option`, then

   ```
   cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "menuentry 'Ubuntu,"
       menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.2.0-26-generic-advanced-a8bbd8f4-68d3-4a3d-836d-a75021372c04' {
       menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.2.0-26-generic-recovery-a8bbd8f4-68d3-4a3d-836d-a75021372c04' {
       menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-50-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-50-generic-advanced-a8bbd8f4-68d3-4a3d-836d-a75021372c04' {
       menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-50-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-50-generic-recovery-a8bbd8f4-68d3-4a3d-836d-a75021372c04'
   ```

   Note the `$menuentry_id_option` for the option you selected at boot.
4. Now let's edit GRUB options to set this item as the default one

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Comment out the `GRUB_DEFAULT` line you have and create a new one, listing the two `$menuentry_id_option` you got earlier, joined with a `>`. After edit, my file looks like this

   ```
   #GRUB_DEFAULT=0
   GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-a8bbd8f4-68d3-4a3d-836d-a75021372c04>gnulinux-5.19.0-50-generic-advanced-a8bbd8f4-68d3-4a3d-836d-a75021372c04"
   ```
5. Save, exit `nano` and run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Reboot and your system should boot fine.

### Further info

- At first I tried to understand if this was a graphic driver issue, by adding the `nomodeset` option on the fly to the default GRUB option ([see here](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/)).
- After confirming it was booting correctly, I tried to boot the 5.19 kernel and noticed it was working both with and without `nomodeset`, so it looked like something was wrong with kernel 6.20
- I installed Nvidia drivers package `nvidia-driver-535`: it solved the boot issue with kernel 6.20, but "night light" function was not working, so I reverted to Nouveau

I'll do further tests and report back if a find a fully working configuration with 6.20.

### Sources

- [How to get out of a stuck boot due to graphic drivers](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/)
- [How to change the default kernel in GRUB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327686)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the key issue here is the failure to load the efi_pstore and drm kernel modules in the newer kernel version. Here's a step-by-step approach to troubleshoot and hopefully resolve the issue:

Safe Mode Boot:
Boot into a safe mode or recovery mode to access a terminal. This will allow you to work on the system without the problematic kernel.

Check Kernel Modules:
Ensure that the modules are present for the newer kernel. Navigate to the appropriate directory:

```
cd /lib/modules/6.2.0.26/kernel/drivers/
```

And then find the modules:

```
find . -name "efi_pstore.ko"
find . -name "drm.ko"
```

Manually Load Modules:
Try to manually load the modules to see if there's an error:

```
modprobe efi_pstore
modprobe drm
```

Review Kernel Logs:
Review the kernel logs for any errors related to these modules:

```
dmesg | grep -i "efi_pstore\|drm"
```

Sometimes, specific kernel boot parameters can cause issues. Review your bootloader's configuration (likely GRUB) to see if there are any unusual parameters set for the new kernel.

Graphics Drivers:
Although you mentioned you are not using Nvidia drivers, the kernel could still be having issues with your RTX 3070. You might consider booting with the nomodeset parameter to bypass any GPU issues during boot. If that works, then it's a clue that the issue is graphics related.

Reinstall Kernel:
It's possible that there was a problem during the kernel upgrade. Consider reinstalling the 6.2.0.26 kernel...